# Source maps not loading at all

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, source-maps

I'm trying to make source maps for AngularJS show in Chrome's developer tools. I made a simple webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <title>Some App</title>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello world! {{ 1+2 }}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

This was saved as `index.html`, then I copied three AngularJS files (`angular.js`, `angular.min.js` and `angular.min.js.map`) straight from [Angular's bower repository](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular) into the `lib` subdirectory, then made sure that the “Enable source maps” option is turned on in the developer tools' settings page. I serve the contents of this directory using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. Yet Chrome doesn't even query the server for the map file—that would show up in the server's logs.

Then I tried loading the source map demos like the [Coffee Script demo](http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/source_mapping/compile.html) or demos linked on [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) page… none of them actually load the map files, which I guess would show up in the “Network” tab.

This is Chrome 28.0.1500.95 on a Debian SID system.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently Chrome handles the “new” `//#` syntax only in Chrome 30. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258349